# How to fix "+" symbol getting place reversed on iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native

I am using a Text component to show a phone number with country code, on android, it looks fine, sth like this:

+123-456789

but on iPhone, the "+" looks sth like that:

123-456789+

The current code is like this:

```
<Text h4 style={styles.details} >
                   +123-456789
</Text>
```

And this is the styling used:

```
 details:{
   color:colors.black,
   alignSelf:'center',
   flexDirection:'row'
 },
```

I don't get why it gets reversed on iPhone, any ideas?

Comment: We're gonna need a whole lot more info before we can help you any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
<Text h4 style={styles.details} >
   {"+123-456789"}
</Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will also display normally in iOS. Look at my code. I've also attached a link.

[Example link](https://snack.expo.io/@taeeh/text-exam)

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          +123-456789
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```